# Apply Publishing Feature to all Subsites with Powershell Sharepoint 2016

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, publishing-site, feature-activation

I am working with a lot of site collections, which each have many subsites. I have custom branding that will only work if the publishing feature is activated on each site and subsite. I tried this:

`$sites = Get-SPSite -WebApplication "https://myWebApp.com/" -Limit All
foreach ($site in $sites)
{
    Enable-SPFeature "PublishingSite" -url $site.url
}`

That only activated publishing on all the root site collections, not the subsites. So then I tried adding this in the loop:

`Get-SPWeb -Site $site.Url -Limit all | % {enable-SPFeature "PublishingSite" -url $_.url}`

When I did that I got this error:

> The specified feature applies to the entire site collection, but the
>   specified URL refers to a particular sub site.  To apply this feature
>   to the entire site  collection, use the root URL
>   'https://myWebApp.com/sites/aSiteCollection'

What do I need to change so that every "SPWeb" can have the publishing feature activated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify the web level feature name to `PublishingWeb`.

Change the `SPWeb` level code as below:

```
Get-SPWeb -Site $site.Url -Limit all | % {enable-SPFeature "PublishingWeb" -url $_.url}
```

`Publishingsite` is the `SharePoint server Publishing infrastructure` feature at site collection level. Its present only at the site collection.

`PublishingWeb` is the `SharePoint server Publishing` feature at the subsite level.This is present only at SPWeb level.

Comment: @Adam - did you try this ? is it working for you, if yes , can you please mark it as answer ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
Activate web scoped feature for all sites in a site collection
$site = Get-SPSite http://portal
$site | Get-SPWeb -limit all | ForEach-Object {Enable-SPFeature -Identity "PublishingWeb" -Url $_.Url}
$site.Dispose()
```

Reference: [Add SharePoint farm solution and bulk activate feature using PowerShell](http://get-spscripts.com/2010/06/install-farm-solution-and-bulk-activate.html)

Comment: Is it necessary to Dispose of the variable?